# Send static methods as parameter and generically call within another method in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, methods, polymorphism

I want to use static methods from one class (of one type),

1. send them to another method in a different class, and
2. call them within the different class's method without explicitly using their names

so as to make the **call generic**.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality? Some pseudo-code that helps exemplify what I'm trying to do:

```
public class A
{
     public static void aMethod1()
     {
          //do something
     }

     public static void aMethod2()
     {
          //do something else
     }
}

public class B
{
     public void bMethod(<Parameter that can take any of A's methods polymorphically>)
     {
          <call ANY method sent in by the parameter with the same line of code>
     }
}

public class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          A obj_A = new A();
          B obj_B = new B();
          obj_B.bMethod(<Send any of A's methods>);
     }
}
```

I may be on the completely wrong path but this is how I imagine it might be done. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In Java, methods are not objects that can be passed around like in some other languages. What you're probably looking for are interfaces, though that won't help you with static methods. If you can use Java 8, you might want to take a look at default methods on interfaces. That might get you close.

Comment: You should look up functional interfaces, they do exactly what you want except that the method isn't declared inside another class, it's not exactly what you want, but the best thing you can probably do.

Comment: @Cyper actually as of Java 8 you can pass methods around as objects. The syntax is a bit wonky but it works

Comment: @Mshnik Do you know what this feature is called? I'd like to take a look.

Comment: @Cypher: [Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: static methods will remain same across all types of A.. you can just call A.method1() without having to use any object of A

Comment: Another approach could be to use reflection, thought that is very slow.

Comment: @Cypher: *"In Java, methods are not objects that can be passed around like in some other languages."* ... Not strictly true as of Java 8.  Lambda expressions are a means of defining *anonymous methods* which provide an abstraction over behavior much like objects provide an abstraction over data.  Lambda expressions (and the related method reference) provide a mechanism for passing behavior as data.

Comment: @scottb Thanks. I'm familiar with lambda's and I read up on what Lukas and Mshnik were referring to (method references). However, it seems to me that these things are just like any other Java callback (passing an object instance around via interface), just with some different syntax. Interesting to know about these things, so thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Using method references:

Declare:

```
public class B
{
     public void bMethod(Runnable runnable)
     {
          runnable.run();
     }
}
```

Now pass [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to `bMethod()`

```
new B().bMethod(A::aMethod1);
new B().bMethod(A::aMethod2);
```

#### Using reflection

Declare:

```
public class B {
     public void bMethod(Method method) {
          try {
              method.invoke(null)
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
     }
}
```

Now pass methods to `bMethod()` [via reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

```
new B().bMethod(A.class.getMethod("aMethod1"));
new B().bMethod(A.class.getMethod("aMethod2"));
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, but it seems he specifically wants `bMethod(..)` to **only** take method references declared in `A`, and not from anywhere else.

Comment: @Mshnik. The OP didn't explicitly say that.

Comment: probably also helpful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Thanks very much! Method references are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can achieve that using reflection.

```
public void bMethod(String name) throws NoSuchMethodException,
  InvocationTargetException,
  IllegalAccessException {
    A.class.getMethod(name).invoke(null);
}
```

Where `name` is a name of your method (be it `aMethod1` or `aMethod2`).

However, this is not a real OOP way and you should really use some other approach instead. For example, define an interface called `Behavior`

```
interface Behavior {
  void run();
}
```

Then You create two different implementations of this interface.

```
class BehaviorA implements Behavior {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Behavior A
  }
}

class BehaviorB implements Behavior {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Behavior B
  }
}
```

Now your `bMethod`'s signature inside of your `B` class can look as follows:

```
void bMethod(Behavior b);
```

And voila! You can pass two different behaviors to your method now, without using ugly reflection-based hacks.